# WordPress WP_Query query event post type for events after current time

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I don't know why I can't get this to work. So I want to get a list of events that are in the future. The event date is stored as a timestamp. I want to order them by the next event first and the next one after that etc.

Here's what I'm using but it's not ordering by the timestamp and it's even showing events that have passed.

```
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'race', 
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'race_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'meta_value' => time()
);
```

So for example there's an event with the timestamp 1540322400 and the time of testing it was 1552474027 so I don't know why that event is being returned.

Then for example an event with the timestamp 1556447400 is showing before in order of an event with the timestamp 1551813600.

In this case I'm using Advanced Custom Fields date and time picker and storing it using a custom value U to store a timestamp.

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to overtly specify a date object comparison for your meta query. Otherwise, your comparison may be comparing strings rather than dates.

You can set a 'type' of `DATETIME` on the meta query comparison.

Try this query:

```
$time = date('U'); // same as ACF format
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'race', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'race_date',
                'value'   => $time,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'    => 'DATETIME' // Try with DATE if necessary
            )
        ),
);
```

### References

- [ACF Manual, date time picker](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/)
- [WP Codex, custom field parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks! That's a bit closer but the old event is still showing and one in April has disappeared but the order is right. This is a real head scratcher for me.

Comment: Have you checked the format that ACF has stored the date for those events - is it possible that those dates were stored in string formats as part of the dev process? Dates can be tricky...

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it's storing it as a string. Maybe I should change the format the date is stored in.